# Group homomorphism $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It seems intuitive that $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z\times \Bbb 2\Bbb Z\simeq\Bbb Z_2$. But what would be a homomorphism $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z_2$ such that it's kernel is $\Bbb Z\times 2\Bbb Z$? I first tried $(a,b)\to a\cdot b$ but it's not a homomorphism. Any help?

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{\Bbb Z\times\phantom{2}\Bbb Z}{\Bbb Z\times2\Bbb Z} \cong \frac{\Bbb Z}{\Bbb Z}\times\frac{\phantom{2}\Bbb Z}{2\Bbb Z}$ mods out the first coordinate entirely, and mods the second coordinate by $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about $(a,b) \mapsto b+2\mathbb Z$? It is a homomorphism (since it is the composition of the projection $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ onto the second coordinate with the quotient map $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z =: \mathbb Z_2$) and its kernel is $$\{(a,b) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z : b+2\mathbb Z = 2\mathbb Z\} = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z : b \in 2\mathbb Z\}.$$

Comment: Note (to OP): this is also the *only* homomorphism that will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way:

1. You only have two elements in $\mathbb Z_2$.
2. An element is either in the kernel or it is not.
3. You already know exactly which elements are in the kernel. Those must map to $0$.
4. By extension, you also know which elements are **not** in the kernel. Those must map into "*some*" element outside the kernel, but there is only one...